# What is the standard port number for mobile webserver

Tags: node.js, server

I am using a different server for handling requests from mobile devices. What port number should I use?

Currently, I am using 8080, 8081, 8082 and 8083 for my desktop browser based requests.

Should I use 7070, 7071, 7072, 7073? or something similar?
Please share your valuable inputs

Comment: Any port above 1024 that is not already in use on either client or server will work just fine.   Likely duplicate of: [How to decide on port number between client and server communication on internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788636/how-to-decide-on-port-number-between-client-and-server-communication-on-internet) and [How to go about choosing a TCP/IP port for a new server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133879/how-should-one-go-about-choosing-a-default-tcp-ip-port-for-a-new-service).

Comment: Thanks, @jfriend00 I was wondering if there were any standard port number for mobile app servers which would be serving requests from m.domainName:portNumber

Comment: No, there is not a standard port number for mobile app servers.  You can see the IANA listings for all standard port numbers in my above referenced posts.  Assuming these are http app servers, If I were you, I'd use port 80 or 443 since they are the least likely to be blocked by anyone and the most likely to be supported by proxies or other infrastructure in the network path.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, I did. Thanks for the recommendation.
I am using 80 for my load balancer :)

Comment: Uhhh, a load balancer is not an end destination and it should be widely configurable.  So, I don't understand why the fact that you have a load balancer should stop you from using port 80 for `m.domainName.com`?  You can configure the load balancer to direct port 80 traffic for m.domainName.com to your mobile app server just fine without changing what it does for other port 80 traffic for some other domain (if you have other port 80 traffic).